# Storing text and using only part of it later

Tags: selenium-ide

Incredibly new to Selenium IDE / Automating tests and currently I am trying to store part of a text, which is a variable to use in later in another web page.

I haven't actually tried much but have been reading quite a few threads but I'm just not grasping the concepts I guess

```
<tr align=center> <td><font size='+1' color='white'><b>Authorization Request - Confirmation Number: 219927</b> </font></td></tr>
```

In this example, I need to be able to store 219927 to use later on another site

The below has passed all of the tests but I seem to not be able to echo the output back on another site:

```
store | xpath=//b[contains(.,'Authorization Request - Confirmation Number: 135085')] | string 
store | 1 | delimiter store | javascript{storedVars['string'].split('- ')[storedVars['delimiter']]} | test 
store | 0 | delimiter1 
store | javascript{storedVars['test'].split(',')[storedVars['delimiter1']]} | output 
echo | ${output}
```

Comment: I currently have: store text | xpath=//b[contains(.,'Authorization Request - Confirmation Number: 219927')] | var1....... echo | ${var1}........ execute script | storedVars | ['var1'].match(/\d+/)

Comment: I now have the following and can't get the echo to type out in a field on another site:   store  | xpath=//b[contains(.,'Authorization Request - Confirmation Number: 135085')] | string
store  | 1 | delimiter   
store  | javascript{storedVars['string'].split('- ')[storedVars['delimiter']]} | test
store  | 0 | delimiter1
store  | javascript{storedVars['test'].split(',')[storedVars['delimiter1']]} | output
echo   | ${output}

Comment: I'm not really an expert in this, so I can't help you personally. But perhaps I can give you tips to improve your chances of getting a reply. For example, try updating your post with the information in these comments. The more you give, the easier it will be to help :)

Comment: Ok, cool. I will certainly do that. Thank you for the help